# How do I get "No Easy Way Out" on "Core?"

Tags: halo-4

The achievement "No Easy Way Out" specifies:

> In Ch 1, Ep 5 of Spartan Ops, survive the enemy assault during the defense on Normal or harder.

I've played "Core" a half dozen times, in co-op, solo, on Normal, Heroic, Legendary, etc...  I've also tried avoiding death in the final section where you defend the artifact, or even the whole Op, but still I haven't unlocked this achievement.  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Core" is Episode 1: Chapter 5.  Note that the achievement specifies Chapter 5: Episode 1.

This is made doubly confusing by the fact that they put the chapter number first, even though chapters are a subset of episodes.  All of the other Spartan Op episode/chapter achievements do this as well.

Therefore, you can't get this achievement by playing the Spartan Op "Core" - it is for a Spartan Op that has yet to be released.

Comment: This confused me also. Why put achievements in the list that you can't get...surely add them when the content is available (That's how it normally works!)

Comment: @SpaceBison simple: to keeep people from selling the game early on, so people will have to buy new games instead of used ones. simple money-making tactic.